# Cleanup php files from virus

Tags: php, bash, sed, virus

I'll get mallwared site hosted on linux hosting. All php files now start from lines:

```
<?php
$md5 = "ad05c6aaf5c532ec96ad32a608566374";
$wp_salt = array( ... );
$wp_add_filter = create_function( ... );
$wp_add_filter(  ... );
?>
```

How I can cleanup it's with bash/sed or something?

Comment: You should probably start clean if you can. I tried cleaning up a site  4x recently (osCommerce) and it ended up being pointless. If you don't have the choice, make a note of all the lines that appear to have been added, check the access logs and do your best to find any suspicious scripts or even executables that have been added to break into your site.

Comment: Can you please tell us which hosting company will do the auto prepend the php code? (So we can avoid the hosting company). I rather think your site is hacked.

Comment: I just got hit by the same thing. Note that md5 line is different for each file.

Comment: @ajreal: It's not necessarily the fault of the hosting company. In my case, the hackers had found an exploit in osCommerce (hosting company is OVH) and uploaded a series of scripts that allowed them to basically do anything like change directory permissions. The last attempt involved an executable outside the www directory. Nuts :) .

Comment: I try to make fun on the OP. The problem is obviously on script, not hosting company

Comment: Are you by chance running phpMyAdmin on the site that got "mallwared"?

Comment: I'd just like to update this, one of our Joomla! sites got attacked by this too. Even worse, if it wasn't for the fact that phpThumb wasn't generating images properly, we'd have never noticed. I highly suggest any developer reading this to pick a few random PHP files from your CMS projects and check them.

Answer (score 5):

You should restore your backup.

Comment: Or "revert" using your version control system.

Comment: good idea, but that's not mine server and itsnt have backups (

Answer (score 1):

```
FILES="*.php"
for f in $FILES
do
  cat $f | grep -v 'wp_salt|wp_add_filter|wp_add_filter' > $f.clean
  mv $f.clean $f
done
```

Comment: Would this not hose any WordPress core files?

Comment: Not sure, but I suppose they do not contain any of these: wp_salt, wp_add_filter, wp_add_filter

Comment: yep, almost the same thing I was use for cleanup

Answer (score 1):

Just a warning, the wp_add_filter() recursively evaluates encoded php code, which in turn calls another script that is encoded and evaluated. This larger script not only injects malicious code throughout your site but appears to collect credentials, and execute other hacks. You should not only clean your site, but make sure the flaw is fixed and any credentials that might have been exposed are changed. In the end, it appears to be a wordpress security issue but I've not confirmed this. I've added some comments on this over at http://www.php-beginners.com/solve-wordpress-malware-script-attack-fix.html, which includes a clean-up script and more information on how to decode the malicious script.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with PHP (fopen, str_replace and fwrite) . There shouldn't be any encoding problems.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit with this on a very full hosting account, every web file full of php?!

Much digging and post reading everywhere I came across this guys cleaner code (see http://www.php-beginners.com/solve-wordpress-malware-script-attack-fix.html) - and tried it on a couple of the least important sites first.

So far so good. Pretty much ready to dig in and utilize it account wide to try and wipe this right off.

Answer (score 0):

The virus/malware seems to be called "!SShell v. 1.0 shadow edition!" and infected my hosting account today. Along with the cleaner at http://www.php-beginners.com/solve-wordpress-malware-script-attack-fix.html, you actually need to discover the folder containing the shell file that gives the hackers full access to your server files and also discover the "wp-thumb-creator.php" that's the file that does all the php injection. I've posted more about this @ my blog: http://www.marinbezhanov.com/web-development/6/malware-alert-september-2011-sshell-v.1.0/